# Delete a record after a period of time automatically in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete

I have a table which has two attributes: ID & Datetime when that record was created.

How can I make a trigger (procedure?) to delete a record after, say, 1 day?

I want a task which executes itself every X time instead of manually having to do it.

Comment: Triggers are like events, they fire when an action takes place (i.e insert, update, delete). What you are talking about is a schedule task. Often in sql server you would create a procedure to delete the rows you want. And then create a sql job to run on a given schedule to execute that procedure.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you to use SQL Server agent and write a stored procedure that deletes every rows that date is passed one day.

You can find how to use Sql server agent jobs here in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/schedule-a-job).

And the stored procedure like :

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE DeleteRows()
AS
BEGIN
DELETE FROM mytable
WHERE (DATEDIFF(DAY,  DATEADD(day, -1, DateColum), GETDATE())) >= 1
END
```

---

Edit :
The number 1 in where statement is days. you can change it to what you want to use.

Comment: You're welcome. I suggest read about sql jobs more so you can use this at best way you want.

Answer (score 0):

The statement to delete a record older than one day is:

```
DELETE FROM tableName WHERE DATEDIFF(day, getdate(), dateColumn) < -1
```

You would need to cron that statement using whatever language you have available, php for instance.

That said of course it's hard to imagine a scenario where you would want to be deleting records in the first place ;)

Comment: Thanks! Can you briefly explain the -1 part? Also, is it possible to make it execute itself daily & automatically? I heard something called SQL Job but I'm not sure.

Comment: About the scenario, it's about forgot password links that are sent via emails - the link should expire after a period of time

Comment: The minus one equates to "one day ago" (ergo yesterday) :)

Comment: These stored procedure guys sound cool though, so that might be what you are looking for :) I'm going to upvote the one I don't understand, since it's probably right! haha

Answer (score 0):

You could create a SQL Job to run after one day (or daily as you want.) and execute a specified stored procedure that carries a simple delete statement.

Follow the next topic:-

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190268.aspx