# Deleting a SQL entry after set amount of day (Set by the user)

Tags: phpmyadmin

Hi we have a site that allows us to share passwords. The following used to delete the entry after a set number of days set by the user. This used to work but now no longer delete the entry. if it falls longer than the set number of days.

```
$sql="DELETE FROM database_name WHERE creation_date < NOW() , INTERVAL days DAY";
```

Im not sure what could have gone wrong as when googling people are saying its correct.

I have also tried the following

```
 $sql="DELETE FROM database_name WHERE creation_date < NOW() - INTERVAL days DAY";
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how this could be done with pure SQL, however, it is doable with SQL server. You could do this for SQL server from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43285172/9813464):

```
DELETE FROM tableName WHERE DATEDIFF(day, getdate(), dateColumn) < -1
```

There is also T-SQL which is an extension that adds some functionalities to SQL where you can create a transaction that would do it. If not, for tasks like this, I always set up a cron job or other similar techniques rather than using SQL